# Pandas index=False still shows column index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using to_html to convert a dataframe to html code. I want to get rid of the row and column index which is showing in the html output. However even after using index=False the column index is still showing in the output. The row index dosen't show up.

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result_input = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID_input,
                            range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
values_input = result_input.get('values', [])
df=pd.DataFrame(values_input)
print(df.to_html(index=False))
```

Please see the image attached. 0-13 are the column index I am not able to get rid of

[image]

Comment: There is no column index in the output normally. Do you mean the column headers? Or maybe you want to remove the first row?

Comment: @PythonSherpa  Question modified with screen grab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no index column in your html output. What you want to remove is the header row. You can achieve this with specifying `header=False`:

```
print(df.to_html(index=False, header=False))
```

Comment: But that row is not in the google sheet. Where did it come from  ?

Comment: You're originial question is answered. Please mark my answer as correct if it answered your initial question and open a new thread. I can not answer your second question based on the information you provided (I see neither the spreadsheet nor do I know which API you are using for reading it).

Comment: Marked as answer .Thanks